# clojure assoc-if and assoc-if-new

Tags: clojure

I want to add an entry to a map but only if the map does not contain the key that I want to add.  I.e. I want to do insert but not update.  For his I created 2 functions:

```
(defn assoc-if [pred coll k v]
  (if pred (assoc coll k v) coll))

(defn assoc-if-new [coll k v]
  (assoc-if (not (contains? coll k)) coll k v))
```

My question is, do these two functions not exist already?

Also, I'm pretty new to Clojure, any tips on the implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(defn assoc-if [pred coll k v]
  (if (pred coll k) (assoc coll k v) coll))

(defn assoc-if-new [coll k v]
  (assoc-if (complement contains?) coll k v))
```

You made a couple of errors:

In

```
(defn assoc-if [pred coll k v]
  (if pred (assoc coll k v) coll))
```

... `pred` is not called. Being neither `false` nor `nil`, its function value will evaluate true. So the function will always return `(assoc coll k v)`.

In

```
(defn assoc-if-new [coll k v]
  (assoc-if (not (contains? coll k)) coll k v))
```

... the first argument to `assoc-if` should be a *predicate* - a function returning a value used for its truth or falsehood. `(not (contains? coll k))` will produce a boolean value, causing an error when `assoc-if` tries to call it as a function.

- Don't supply the arguments explicitly: `assoc-if` concocts the call
  internally.
- If you want to invert the logical result, you have to adapt the
  *function* `contains?` to a *function* that returns the logically inverted result. 
  The standard function `complement` does this.

Comment: Duh! I feel so stupid with some of the mistakes I made :)  Thanks.

Comment: This is implicit in shmish111's strategy as revised by Thumbnail, but I thought it needed to be said explicitly: `(defn assoc-if-new [m k v] (if (contains? m k) m (assoc m k v)))` is simpler and easier to understand if you don't need `assoc-if`, and it seems potentially slightly more efficient than @optevo's elegant `merge` version: The simple version does precisely what's needed, and no more--it doesn't generate a temporary map, or run through a few more operations that happen in the source for `merge`.  That said, this is about a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 20):

With [`merge`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/merge) the right hand map will always overwrite the left hand map so if you reverse your arguments and put them in a map you get the same behaviour:

```
(assoc-if-new {:a 1 :b 2} :b 3)
;=> {:a 1, :b 2}

(assoc-if-new {:a 1 :b 2} :c 3)
;=> {:c 3, :a 1, :b 2}

(merge {:b 3} {:a 1 :b 2})
;=> {:a 1, :b 2}

(merge {:c 3} {:a 1 :b 2})
;=> {:b 2, :a 1, :c 3}
```

In other words:

```
(defn assoc-if-new [coll k v] (merge {k v} coll))
```

Comment: I wish I could set both answers as correct but I had to pick one!

Comment: IMHO, using merge is the idiomatic answer, and the reason why the suggested functions do not exist.

Comment: @optevo solution is clever, but there is a performance penalty. If the `assoc-if-new` function is used with big maps and in a computing intensive loop, I would definitely go for @Mars solution.  With [criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) benchmark, it takes **5.3ms** to `assoc-if-new` 100000 kv-pairs with @Mars solution and **25.9** with @optevo 's `merge` one.